# About photos going onto other Apple products

Tags: icloud

Have about 2000 work photos on my Mac mini which I do not want on my iPhone 5 or my iPad Air....but I would like photos I take on either of those to appear on my Mac mini.....how do I configure in settings so I can do this?

Answer (score 1):

In the iCloud settings of the Mac minis turn on photos. They will both sync photos.

To not have the photos synced to the phone simply don’t have the photos option enabled in the iCloud settings.